# Populate Dropdownlist in Table Row

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application, i want to populate a dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist selected value in the same row table using Ajax, this is the code i used:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Category> categories = _dbcontext.Category.ToList();
    ViewBag.ListCategories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");            
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetStockByCat(int CatId)
{
    List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
    stocks = _dbcontext.Stock.Where(s => s.CategoryId == CatId).ToList();
    SelectList stocksList = new SelectList(stocks, "StockId", "Name");
    return Json(stocksList);
}
```

View:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.StockItems.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.ListCategories, null, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetStocks(this)" })</td>
            <td><select id="stocks" name="stocks" class="form-control></select></td>
        </tr>
     }
    </tbody>
</table>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetStocks(dropdown1) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        var dropdown2 = dropdown1.closest('tr').find('#stocks');
        dropdown2.html(procemessage).show();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetStockByCat", "Stock")';
    
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { CatId: dropdown1.value},
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>---------</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += '<option value="' + data[x].value + '">' + data[x].text + '</option>';
                }
                dropdown2.html(markup).show();
                
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });        
    }
```

But  Stock dropdown list isn't populating, it remains empty. How to solve this?

Comment: What does `data` has in it ? Check your network tab to see if request is send properly and what response is return back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and I'm not sure if it's your pasting error or your own, but I chose to point it out for you anyway.

`<td><select id="stocks" name="stocks" class="form-control></select></td>` missed `"` , it should be `<td><select id="stocks" name="stocks" class="form-control"></select></td>`.

If you don't apply some special library, then `dropdown1.closest('tr').find('#stocks')` will report an error, you can change it to `$(dropdown1).closest('tr').find('#stocks')`.

Please make sure the `stocksList` returned by the `GetStockByCat` method is not empty, change the above error, then you should see that the `Stock dropdown list` is filled correctly.

No matter what the result is, you can view the error message through the browser's developer tools, and add breakpoints to debug step by step:
[image]

**Edit:**

You can add breakpoints to see the contents of `$(dropdown1).closest('tr')` and `dropdown2`:

`$(dropdown1).closest('tr').html()`, `dropdown2.html()`, `dropdown2.length`
[image]

Comment: When i changed dropdown1.closest('tr').find('#stocks') to $(dropdown1).closest('tr').find('#stocks') the dropdown1 populate all dropdown2 in all rows not only the one in the same row

Comment: Hi @user3309231, I did not have your problem, you can follow my updated way to debug step by step to find out where the problem occurs.

Comment: I found the mistake i made, it works now thanks.